# How to use batch file to insert a character after 5th character

Tags: batch-file, rename, file-rename

I am trying to rename multiple files using batch script. 
Example: 
before 28451WZ
after  284_51WZ

so far, I know how to insert a suffix and prefix, but having trouble to insert a character at specific position.

`@echo off
for %%A in (*.pdf ^/ find /i /v ) do ren "%%~fA" "-%%~nA.*"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in string substitution features of cmd.

```
@echo off

echo Setting envar to 'helloworld'
set "envar=helloworld"
echo envar=`%envar%`
echo.

echo Using substr
echo   example: `%envar:~0,5%_%envar:~5%`
echo.

echo.
echo Additional notes:
echo.
echo If you are _not_ using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` you will need
echo to assign the result to a new variable using:
echo set "envar2=%envar:~0,5%_%envar:~5%"
echo     Note the `_` here   ^^
set "envar2=%envar:~0,5%_%envar:~5%"
echo.
echo   envar2=`%envar2%`
echo.

echo If you _are_ using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` you will need
echo to use variable expansion (ie: use the `!` instead of the `%%`):
echo set "envar=!envar:~0,5!_!envar:~5!"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "envar=!envar:~0,5!_!envar:~5!"
echo.
echo   envar=`%envar%`
echo.
endlocal
```

The batch file above produces the following output:

```
Setting envar to 'helloworld'
envar=`helloworld`

Using substr
  example: `hello_world`


Additional notes:

If you are _not_ using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` you will need
to assign the result to a new variable using:
set "envar2=%envar:~0,5%_%envar:~5%"
    Note the `_` here   ^

  envar2=`hello_world`

If you _are_ using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` you will need
to use variable expansion (ie: use the `!` instead of the `%`):
set "envar=!envar:~0,5!_!envar:~5!"

  envar=`hello_world`
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response!! I was able to figured it out because of your example!

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to know the answer.

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*.pdf) do (
set "name=%%A" 
set "name=!name:~0,5!_!name:~5!"
ren "%%A" "!name!"
)
```